# Scala equivalent of Google Collections Lists.partition

Tags: scala, guava

I am looking for a function that will partition a list into fixed size sublists, exactly what [Lists.partition](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition(java.util.List%2C%20int)) from Google Collections library does. 
I couldn't find such method in the Scala Collections API. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could Nermin or someone with sufficient permissions edit the post to fix the URL? Replacing the comma or space with its urlencoded equivalent should do it, I believe.

Comment: This happens to be an exact duplicate, but the other question isn't showing up on the related links.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The method you are looking for is "grouped".  A slight difference from the partition function is that it returns an Iterator of Lists rather than a List of Lists.  That may be fine, or you may need to convert it using the Iterator.toList function

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
println(list.grouped(2).toList) //prints List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5))
```

Comment: And while you're at it, familiarize yourself with the similar `Iterable#sliding` (technically, introduced in `IterableLike`). It creates (potentially) overlapping windows of fixed size into a sequence.